# Maximum number of concurrent TCP/IP connections - Win XP SP3

Tags: windows, tcp

Does anyone know what is the maximum number of concurrent TCP/IP connections on Windows XP SP3? I am trying to load test a machine and would like to know what is the max number of tcp connections that can be opened by an application (in my case, java application) towards that machine.

Comment: Check this SO question and its answers! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/594336/what-is-the-upper-limit-on-the-number-of-open-sockets-i-can-have-in-win2003-serve

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that often you may be limited by the number of outbound connections supported on the client machine rather than by the number of concurrent connections possible. See this [Socket Bind Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085675/socket-bind-error/1087525#1087525) for how to tune `MAX_USER_PORT` to enable more outbound connections from the machine running the tests.

Answer (score 1):

I found some very useful information here:

http://smallvoid.com/article/winnt-tcpip-max-limit.html