# C++ socket option reuse port

Tags: c++, sockets, multicast

I have a problem with a c++ socket.
I'm using CAsyncSocket from MFC that i want to join a multicast group.
Also I need to have multiple listener on this group and here is where i get in trouble.
I found some examples on the web but it doesn't seems to work.
Here is my code:

```
//create socket on port 17233   
BOOL bRet = Create(17233,SOCK_DGRAM, FD_READ);

//set reuse socket option  
BOOL bMultipleApps = TRUE;
bRet = SetSockOpt(SO_REUSEADDR, (void*)&bMultipleApps, sizeof(BOOL), SOL_SOCKET);

//join multicast group
ip_mreq m_mrMReq;           // Contains IP and interface of the host group
m_mrMReq.imr_multiaddr.s_addr = inet_addr((LPCSTR)"224.30.0.1");    /* group addr */ 
m_mrMReq.imr_interface.s_addr = htons(INADDR_ANY);      /* use default */

int uRes =setsockopt(m_hSocket, IPPROTO_IP, IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP, (char FAR *)&m_mrMReq, sizeof(m_mrMReq));
```

There are no errors when i run this.
But when i try to run another instance of the app it fails to create a new socket on that port because the port is in use.

I have done this in C# and it worked fine like this:

```
IPEndPoint ipep = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, port);
s.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, 1);
s.Bind(ipep);
IPAddress ip = IPAddress.Parse(mcastGroup);
s.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.IP, SocketOptionName.AddMembership, new MulticastOption(ip, IPAddress.Any));
s.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.IP,SocketOptionName.MulticastTimeToLive, int.Parse("1"));
```

So if any body sees a problem with my code or have some tips i will gladly appreciated.

**EDIT 1:**
Is CAsyncSocket a TCP socket?

**EDIT 2:**
After reading [Can two applications listen to the same port?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694144/can-two-application-listen-to-the-same-port)
I think i made a confusion. I need a Multicast UDP port that can be access by multiple application using SO_REUSEADDR

**Edit for Clarification:**

```
BOOL bRet = Create(17233,SOCK_DGRAM, FD_READ)
```

Creates an UDP socket and bind's to to port 17223.
For `SetSockOpt(SO_REUSEADDR, (void*)&bMultipleApps, sizeof(BOOL), SOL_SOCKET);` to work you need to set it before binding  as @Hasturkun said.
The final working code looks like this:

```
    BOOL bRet = Socket(SOCK_DGRAM, FD_READ);
    if(bRet != TRUE)
    {
        UINT uErr = GetLastError();
        std::cout<<"Error:"<<uErr<<std::endl;
        return FALSE;
    }else{
        std::cout<<"Create sock: OK"<<std::endl;
    }

    //add reuse
    BOOL bMultipleApps = TRUE;      /* allow reuse of local port if needed */
    SetSockOpt(SO_REUSEADDR, (void*)&bMultipleApps, sizeof(BOOL), SOL_SOCKET);

    //bind
    bRet = Bind(17233, NULL);
    if(bRet != TRUE)
    {
        UINT uErr = GetLastError();
        std::cout<<"Error(BIND):"<<uErr<<std::endl;
    }else{
        std::cout<<"BIND sock: OK"<<std::endl;
    }
```

Thanks,
Gabriel

;

Comment: I guess you should close this question and open another one, since the subject has changed.

Comment: The question was "how can i open multiple sockets on the same port using SO_REUSEADDR" and the answer is (thanks to Hasturkun) by binding the socket after the socket option is set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to separate the creation of the socket from the binding, create the socket using [`Socket`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/casyncsocket-class?view=vs-2019#socket), eg.

```
BOOL bRet = Socket(SOCK_DGRAM, FD_READ);
```

Then bind it with [`Bind`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/casyncsocket-class?view=vs-2019#bind) after setting the sockopt

```
BOOL bMultipleApps = TRUE;
bRet = SetSockOpt(SO_REUSEADDR, (void*)&bMultipleApps, sizeof(BOOL), SOL_SOCKET);

bRet = Bind(17233, NULL);
```

Comment: that is exactly what I was looking for... except there is a problem .. when I call bRet = Bind(17233, NULL); it returns FLASE with error 10022(invalid parameter)

Comment: @Gabriel: I've updated my answer, you need to create the socket using Socket. I expected Create(0..) to not bind from some reason.

Answer (score 1):

This happens, i guess, because you are binding a client socket to a specific port and address. Maybe on its constructor:

`BOOL bRet = Create(17233,SOCK_DGRAM, FD_READ);`

You should not binding a client socket to an address. Let windows manage this for you. You should have a option to not create the socket passing a specific port, or if you do not, you should create the socket using another port.

Also, the `BOOL bMultipleApps = TRUE;` option does not work the way you think it does. It sets a linger option in the socket, but once created and listening, the socket (i mean the socket port) cannot be used in other applications no mather what you do.

Check this out: [so-linger-and-closing-socketswinsock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2828078/so-linger-and-closing-socketswinsock)

**EDIT:**

I also dont know that the value of `port` in your c# code:

`IPEndPoint ipep = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, port);`

Are you sure that `port` does not get a different value every time you run the app?

As I said, try to create the socket in a different port to see what happens. Google for `so_linger` to know what it means.

**EDIT 2:**

Take a look at: [Can two application listen to the same port?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694144/can-two-application-listen-to-the-same-port)

**EDIT 3:**

Maybe your c# code:

```
IPEndPoint ipep = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, port);
```

is binding the address to a different NIC. Do you have 2 nics at the same computer? If you do, you can bind the same port in both of them.

**EDIT 4:**

Example of using UDP sockets: [Sending & Receiving UDP Datagrams with MFC's CAsyncSocket](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/UDP_with_CAsyncSocket.aspx)

Comment: if I dont call Create(bind the socket) i cant call  SetSockOpt

Comment: I did not say you should no create. I just said that you are trying to use the same port in 2 applications. Thats not possible.

Comment: So c# s.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, 1); is different from SetSockOpt(SO_REUSEADDR, (void*)&bMultipleApps, sizeof(BOOL), SOL_SOCKET); ?

Comment: I dont think so, but i am not 100% sure because I am not a c# programmer. Give it a try: change the socket port when you run the second app to see what happens.

Comment: if i change the socket port it works. my problem is i can run to listeners on the same port

Comment: IPEndPoint ipep = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, port); port=17233 I am sure that is the same port , i can open as many instances of app(listener) that i want and then when i send something with the sender all off those instances receive the data

Comment: No you cant. You cant have 2 sockets opened at the same port. Ports once used are reserved and theres nothing you can do to have 2 apps running at the same port. If it is a client socket, you should change the port, but if it is a socket server you better re-think your code.

Comment: Hmm CAsyncSocket is a TCP socket? i need a udp multicast

Comment: It probably is, but i am not sure. I will google that and get back to you.

Comment: Ok, found it. It can create UDP multicast but its not the wayt you are doing. check this out: http://simplesamples.info/MFC/UDPSendReceive.php or http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/UDP_with_CAsyncSocket.aspx

Comment: Edit 4 is from where i started... it doesn't work with SO_REUSEADDR

Comment: It it fully possible to use the same port for UDP. I.e. have multiple applications binding to the same port. However, one must create things for reuse or this will not work.

Comment: It is possible for UDP, but not for TCP which is what he is using.

Comment: I'm not using TCP. BOOL bRet = Create(17233,SOCK_DGRAM, FD_READ); creates an UDP socket

Answer (score 1):

If [boost](http://www.boost.org) is an option for you, consider using Asio for this. It is very straight-forward and [this](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/boost_asio/example/multicast/receiver.cpp) example shows a simple multicast receiver.

The important part for multiple listeners is:

```
socket_.set_option(boost::asio::ip::udp::socket::reuse_address(true));
```

If you're unclear what your application is doing, just run `netstat` and you'll see e.g. the sockets and how they are bound (IP, port and protocol):

```
netstat -an
```

...and look for the port you're interested in. If you run multiple applications listening to the same port you should see multiple entries for the same port with UDP as protocol.