# What's the upper bound connections of TServerSocket in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, winsock

Actually I'm trying the ability of TServerSocket in Delphi, and found always around 10K connections are activate, and for the rest, although they're showing me the status "Connected", but still, they cannot receive any message, and for sure, my server socket is broadcasting the same messages to all of them.

So, what's the limit of the TServerSocket? Why there's no data traffic even when connected? Is there any options i can turn?

BTW, I'm using Delphi5.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: How and where do you see the status "Connected"? Please show some example code.

Comment: This isn't anything to do with Delphi. It's purely a Winsock question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/594336/what-is-the-upper-limit-on-the-number-of-open-sockets-i-can-have-in-windows-serv

Comment: @David: I wonder what fraction of the questions in the Delphi tag that are essentially pure Win32 questions. It might be considerable.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand indeed. Just trying to point out that the limit is at a different abstraction layer.

Comment: **Closely related, but not an answer**: The number of open TCP sockets are limited by the OS; it seems to be one of the M$ ways to force you to buy a new OS instead of the perfectly working but outdated (You already paid for it.) OS. In windows XP for example this limit was initially maxint, but SP2 limited it to 1000 and SP3 to 5 connections.